# Gulpfile doesn't work with import X from './X' statements

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I am using WPGulp to build my assets for a WordPress theme, but I am faced with a weird issue and unfortunately, I cannot find any solution.

My current problem is that the statements like `import ModuleName from './modules/ModuleName'` doesn't work, and I get an error message in the browser console like this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Inside the compiled source code, the line that has the problem is like that:

`var _Router = _interopRequireDefault(require("../util/Router"));`

I have try to customize the Gulpfile of the [WPGulp](https://github.com/ahmadawais/WPGulp/blob/master/src/gulpfile.babel.js) to make it work, but I can't make fix it.

One of the solutions I tried, but didn't worked is to add the modules options in the `@babel/preset-env` properties and set all possible options `amd`, `umd`, `systemjs`, etc, but none of them worked.

Any idea on how to solve that problem? Am I doing something in wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to upgrade Node and/or use `--experimental-modules` flag.  You can also set an env var in your shell:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-modules"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately didn't work this solution :(